# I got the error failed to load module script on prod server in VueJs

Tags: php, vue.js

I have deployed my vueJs code at ipage domain but when I open the domain I got the error failed to load module script.

[image]

I am expecting that my prod server working fine but getting error

Comment: Does your code work locally? Why do we have a PHP tag in your question? Where are you hosting it? How are you deploying it? Could you please provide us with some details on top of what I've asked too?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to build your vuejs app

```
    npm run build
```

When Vue builds the app, by default it assumes that index.html will be in the root, as in http://my-server.com/index.html, therefore the base URL is /. so please be sure that index.html is in the public folder which your server points to and update me with your case i am here to help!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).